# how to declare a new structure

Tags: c, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree by reading lines from a file.

```
  while(fgets(p, 1024, fp))
  {
     struct node child;
     child.str = (char *)malloc(plen);      
     strcpy(child.str,p);
     insert(&tree,&child);
  }
```

Now the problem is that I can not seem to find a way to make a complete new copy of child, instead it just changes its values every time the while loop restarts.

Comment: Not enough space for the `strcpy`: you didn't take the string terminator into account.

Comment: And *never cast the malloc result in C*.

Comment: @pmg: that's bogus. You don't know what plen is.

Comment: @Jens: you're right --- but I'm willing to bet a [virtual beer](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01088/connected-graphics_1088863a.jpg) it' s `strlen(p)` :)

Comment: what is `plen`? And you should do `child.str = malloc(plen+1)` because if `plen == strlen(p)` then you have a problem.

Comment: plen is a set value, is declared outside.

Comment: @Jens: oops ... seems like I owe you a virtual beer

Comment: @pmg: I've had enough booze for today. Upvoting my short answer below would be nice, though :-)

Comment: This is not C++. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: "I'm willing to bet a virtual beer it' s strlen(p)" -- it *can't* be, because that has to be calculated after the fgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the pointer-to-child (`&child`) isn't changing. You can convince yourself of this by printing it out:

```
printf("address of child = %p\n", &child);
```

Solution: You also need to allocate the node as well:

```
struct node*child = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You can then assign `child.str` as you were, now using pointer-syntax:

```
child->str = (char *)malloc(plen);      
strcpy(child->str,p);
```

...and because the child is a pointer, you don't need the ampersand here:

```
insert(&tree,child);
```

Comment: Yea I noticed that whenever I changed the value of the string inside child then the other node would receive that same value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's `child->str` and not `child.str`

Comment: By the way, don't cast the return value of `malloc()` -- that's a good way to hide errors.

Comment: ... and for that matter, be mindful of the fact that `strcpy()` cannot check errors for you.

Comment: How would I be able to check for a NULL regarding a node, since when the structure is created it assigns a pointer value to both left and right. These pointers do not lead anywhere, and (parent->right != NULL) returns true even though there is no values there

Comment: You can use `calloc()` or you can use `malloc()` and `memset()`: I'd prefer the `memset()` because it's explicit.

Comment: Well the thing with malloc was that for some reason  I could not check for null nodes (the pointer was set but of course the node was not initialized) A check for null pointer returns false and a check for null node gives a segmentation fault. I had to use calloc since it initializes everything to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say without seeing `insert()`. My guess is that your automatic `struct node` goes out of scope at each iteration. A pointer to such a variable is no longer valid.

Comment: +1: you could also note that the memory allocated gets leaked when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: @pmg Not if insert allocates a struct node and copies to that the contents of the node passed to it, which is assumed to just be a temporary holder. This is even a reasonable approach, *given that its usage is well-documented*. (BTW, this is just the way one would do things in C++, especially with the new move semantics.)

Comment: If `insert()` copies the contents of the node, the fact it goes out of scope is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1):

if you define into a function in this way

```
struct node child;
```

This is a temporary memory so after going out of the function there is a risk tat you loose data. so you have to define the struct dynamically with `malloc` or `calloc`

```
struct node *child = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

or

```
struct node *child = calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
```

the calloc allow the allocation of memory and set it to 0